# Cross compile libtheora with msys

Tags: ffmpeg, cross-compiling, msys

I don't really have any experience cross compiling so there is probably a simple solution to my problem.  I downloaded libogg 1.3.1 from http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/ogg/libogg-1.3.1.tar.gz and libtheora from http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/theora/libtheora-1.1.1.tar.bz2.  First I compile and libogg using these commands (in MSYS, when in the extracted directory):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-static
make clean && make -j4
make install
```

and it looks like everything works (no errors reported and I see libogg files in /usr/local/x86_64-w64-mingw32).

I also compile and install libvorbis and libSDL with similar commands (downloads found in links on http://www.theora.org/downloads/)

I then try to compile libtheora and it fails at the configure.  Here is the command I run:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-static
```

and the result is an error about not finding the libogg library (below is the end of the configure output):

```
checking for OGG... no
checking for Ogg... no
*** Could not run Ogg test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means Ogg was incorrectly installed
*** or that you have moved Ogg since it was installed.
configure: error:
    libogg is required to build this package!
    please see http://www.xiph.org/ for how to
    obtain a copy.
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Try a `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: based on https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/blob/master/cross_compile_ffmpeg.sh, you need to install libvorbis, libogg first, then basically install it the normal way: https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/blob/master/cross_compile_ffmpeg.sh#L792

Comment: I know it must be late, but [this tutorial](http://www.programering.com/a/MzM1cTNwATk.html) might help.